# Retrieve 0 or more matches from comma separated list inside parenthesis using regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to retrieve matches from a comma separated list that is located inside parenthesis using regular expression. *(I also retrieve the version number in the first capture group, though that's not important to this question)*

What's worth noting is that the expression should ideally handle all possible cases, where the list could be empty or could have more than 3 entries = 0 or more matches in the second capture group.

The expression I have right now looks like this:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
SomeText\/(.*)\s\(((,\s)?([\w\s\.]+))*\)
```

The string I am testing this on looks like this:

```
SomeText/1.0.4 (debug, OS X 10.11.2, Macbook Pro Retina)
```

Result of this is:

```
1.  [6-11]  `1.0.4`
2.  [32-52] `, Macbook Pro Retina`
3.  [32-34] `, `
4.  [34-52] `Macbook Pro Retina`
```

The desired result would look like this:

```
1.  [6-11]  `1.0.4`
2.  [32-52] `debug`
3.  [32-34] `OS X 10.11.2`
4.  [34-52] `Macbook Pro Retina`
```

According to the image above (as far as I can see), the expression should work on the test string. What is the cause of the weird results and how could I improve the expression?

---

*I know there are other ways of solving this problem, but I would like to use a single regular expression if possible. Please don't suggest other options.*

Comment: The issue is that you think that applying a quantifier you can get all *captures*. This is not possible in PHP.

Comment: In PHP, you can try using [`(?:SomeText\/([^()]*)\s*\(|(?!^)\G),?\s*([^(),]*)(?=[^()]*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/kX1kL8/1) It outputs some rubbish, too, but you can actually seive the `$matches` after `preg_match_all` with a bit of code. As I say, it is not possible to use *capturing groups* the way you showed, because only the last captured value is kept in the capturing group memory buffer.

Comment: Do it with multiple regexes for simplicity.  Split it into the part with parens and the part without, and then parse each of them separately.  Your code will be much simpler and much easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: There are many, maybe even a lot simpler ways of achieving what I want. However, I wanted to see if it is possible to achieve this only using one regex.

Comment: `(,\s)` captures the comma-space because you didn't make it anonymous with `?:` like so: `(?:,\s)`

Comment: Can you provide some more sample inputs & outputs?

Comment: By use of the [\G anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) there are many ways [like this with capture groups](https://regex101.com/r/tZ8nF3/1) [or this one without](https://regex101.com/r/jB7yT9/1) (also depending on your input).

Comment: @bobblebubble Your expressions are 100% correct on all my test inputs and they can handle empty lists. If you post this comment as an answer, I will gladly accept it :)

Comment: @DominikHadl Great that works for you! Restored and updated my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the [\G anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) works best here for binding the match to an entry point. This regex is designed for input that is always similar to the sample that is provided in your question.

```
(?<=SomeText\/|\G(?!^))[(,]? *\K[^,)(]+
```

- `(?<=SomeText\/|\G)` the [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is the part where matches should be glued to
- `\G` matches where the previous match ended `(?!^)` but don't match start
- `[(,]? *\` matches optional opening parenthesis or comma followed by any amount of space
- [\K resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match
- `[^,)(]+` matches the wanted characters, that are none of `(` `)` `,`

[Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jB7yT9/1) (grab matches of `$0`)

---

Another idea with use of [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

```
SomeText\/([^(]*)\(|\G(?!^),? *([^,)]+)
```

This one without lookbehind is a bit more accurate (it also requires the opening parenthesis), of better performance (needs fewer steps) and probably easier to understand and maintain.

- `SomeText\/([^(]*)\(` the entry anchor and version is captured here to `$1`
- `|\G(?!^),? *([^,)]+)` or glued to previous match: capture to `$2` one or more characters, that are not `,` `)` preceded by optional space or comma.

[Another demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tZ8nF3/1)

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with a varying number of groups, regex ain't the best.  Solve it in two steps.

First, break down the statement using a simple regex:

```
SomeText\/([\d.]*) \(([^)]*)\)

1.  [9-14]  `1.0.4`
2.  [16-55] `debug, OS X 10.11.2, Macbook Pro Retina`
```

Then just `explode` the second result by ',' to get your groups.

Comment: Yes, much easier like that. But I guess you meant `explode`, not `split`.

Comment: Thanks, there are various ways of solving my problem, but I intentionally wanted to solve this using 1 regular expression (no matter the performance).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, stribizhev was close:

[`(?:SomeText\/([^() ]*)\s*\(|(?!^)\G),?\s*([^(),]+)(?=[^()]*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/kX1kL8/3)

Just had to make that one class expect at least one match

[`(?:SomeText\/([0-9.]+)\s*\(|(?!^)\G),?\s*([^(),]+)(?=[^()]*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/kX1kL8/4) is a little more clear as long as the version number is always numbers and periods.

Comment: Those expressions are very and very close to what I need, however they don't seem to handle well empty list (no content inside parenthesis), as they stop returning the version number.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to come up with something more elegant than this (though this *does actually* work):

```
SomeText\/(.*)\s\(([^\,]+)?\,?\s?([^\,]+)?\,?\s?([^\,]+)?\,?\s?([^\,]+)?\,?\s?([^\,]+)?\,?\s?([^\,]+)?\,?\s?\)
```

Obviously, the

```
([^\,]+)?\,?\s?
```

is repeated **6 times**.

(It can be repeated any number of times and it will work for any number of comma-separated items equal to or below that number of times).

I tried to shorten the long, repetitive list of `([^\,]+)?\,?\s?` above to

```
(?:([^\,]+)\,?\s?)*
```

but it doesn't work and my knowledge of regex is not currently good enough to say why not.

Comment: Thanks, but the important thing is the the number of values/parameters can vary, so I don't know how many matches there will be and I can't have a regex that works on specific count of values.

Comment: Yes, I got that - so to cover all cases, you could repeat `([^\,]+)?\,?\s?` 100 times (for example) and it would work for anything from 0 to 100 comma-separated values. But, as I mentioned above, it's a terribly inelegant regex (even though it does actually work).

Answer (score -1):

This should solve your problem. Use the code you already have and add something like this. It will determine where commas are in your string and delete them.
Use trim() to delete white spaces at the start or the end.

`$a = strpos($line, ",");
$line = trim(substr($line, 55-$a));`

I hope, this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I am asking for a solution using regular expression in this question. I know there are other options, but I wish not to use them.